# How to pass a url with a jsession id to a webscraper

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, jsessionid

I am completely new to webscraping with some informal coding experience. I am trying to write a webscraper in Python for [this page](https://app2.msci.com/webapp/indexperf/pages/IEIPerformanceRegional.jsf). If I change the parameters, I get a `jsessionid`, e.g. "`jsessionid=E67785F713193F21D92FE64DBB7E1966`" appended to the end.

Right now, I am trying to access the page like this:

```
session = requests.Session()

session.post("https://app2.msci.com/webapp/indexperf/pages/IEIPerformanceRegional.jsf", 
             data=dict(jsessionid="E67785F713193F21D92FE64DBB7E1966"))

url = "insert_url_because_can't_post_more_than_two_links.jsf"

response = session.get(url)
```

However, when I do this, I am still getting the results from the original page. Most of the resources I found related to logging in to a page with an email and password. What is the best way to pass in a `jsessionid`?